# How do I find the difference of time that I have imported from my data set containing time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to subtract two time instance that I have imported from `tt.txt` file. But the argument to `strptime` must be a `string`(in '%H.%M' format). How can I solve this problem?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
data = np.genfromtext('tt.txt', delimiter= ' ')
sn = data[ :, ][ :,0]
dt = data[ :, ][ :,1]  # dt = depature time, 2nd column of table
at = data[ :, ][ :,2]  # at = arrival time, 3rd column of table
str1 = dt[3]
str2 = at[3]
start = datetime.strptime(str1, '%H.%M')
end = datetime.strptime(str2, '%H.%M')
c = end - start
print(c)
```

Comment: Can you please provide example to tt.txt line?

Comment: In what format you have the time instances?